# Calling and executable with arguements and getting its STDOUT more efficiently in a Python Script

Tags: python, performance, subprocess, gdal

I'm writing a script that takes longitude and latitude and runs them through an executable called *gdallocationinfo*. The executable takes the latitude and longitude as its arguments and returns its STDOUT as the value for that coordinate. I've been reading about sub-processes and I was wondering if this is the most efficient way to implement this if I want to run alot of points. It seems to be taking a really long time.

```
def gdalgetpointdata(longitude,latitude):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["gdallocationinfo","C:\Users\data\pop","-wgs84","-valonly","{0}".format(longitude),"{0}".format(latitude)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (out, err) = proc.communicate()
    return int(out)
```

Is there a better way to call this executable without having to make a new sub-process every time I run my function? Is there something I could do to speed it up?

As a side note I know that if you run the executable from the command line it will keep accepting STDIN and giving ouputs in STDOUT until you tell it to quit()

Comment: I'm on a windows 7 computer running python 2.7 using the OSGeo4W shell

Comment: Yes, it should be more effective to reuse the same process for different coordinates: how to do it depends on `gdallocationinfo` or its analogs (read their docs). Unless `.communicate()` does something stupid; the performance should be limited only by how fast `gdallocationinfo` can produces data. Create a dummy script that emulates `gdallocationinfo` output but as fast as possible and test with it various options e.g., see whether changing `bufsize` parameter has any effect in your environment. Add the results to your question. Specify how much faster do you need it to be.

Comment: What is `len(out)`? You could drop `shell=True` and provide the full path to the executable if necessary, to avoid spawning `%CompSpec%` without a need. Unrelated: `"{0}".format(longitude)` could be written as `str(longitude)`. Use raw-string literals: `r"C:\User\t.."` instead of `"C:\User\t.."`.

Comment: thats a great suggestion, when I timed it at work today it took .15 seconds, but first thing at work tomorrow I will create the dummy function to test the other parameters. I was planning on running hundreds millions of points across it so every millisecond counts.

Comment: If you need 100s millions points then you should probably use a library function instead of spawning a subprocess, [code example](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/29632)

Comment: I decided the most efficient thing would be to just use one sub process and pipe the outputs

Answer (score 3):

The utility can do multiple coordinates with one call. For example, prepare a simple `coords.txt` text file with coordinate pairs:

```
1.0 2.0
3.0 4.0
5.0 6.0
```

Then pipe it *in* and *out* of `gdallocationinfo` from an OSGeo4W shell:

```
gdallocationinfo -wgs84 -valonly raster.tif < coords.txt > values.txt
```

which will make a `values.txt` file with the value for each coordinate. You can do the same with Popen with PIPE stdin and stdout arguments.

```
coords = [(1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0), (5.0, 6.0)]
coord_txt = ''.join(['{0} {1}\n'.format(*c) for c in coords])
p = subprocess.Popen(
    ['gdallocationinfo', r'C:\path\to\raster.tif', '-wgs84', '-valonly'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
values_txt, err = p.communicate(coord_txt)
values = values_txt.splitlines()
```

`values` will be a list of values, the same length as `coords`.

Comment: you could [write input, read output incrementally](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31072926/4279)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just finished reading about pipes and that seems to be the most efficient way to do this. Then dealing with the outputs.txt in python

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of [@Mike T's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31063945/4279) that passes input, reads output dynamically (not tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread

def pump_input(pipe, coords):
    with pipe:
        for longitude, latitude in coords:
            print(longitude, latitude, file=pipe)

p = Popen(['gdallocationinfo', r'C:\path\to\raster.tif', '-wgs84', '-valonly'],
          shell=True, #NOTE: don't use a list argument with shell=True on POSIX
          stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=-1,
          universal_newlines=True)
Thread(target=pump_input, args=[p.stdin, coords]).start()
with p.stdout:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(int(line))
if p.wait() != 0:
   raise Error
```

It might be more efficient to [use GDAL's Python bindings instead](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/29632).

Comment: Awesome thank you for writing this out, Its alot faster using pipes instead of spawning a new process every point, this is exactly what I was trying to figure out